# Excel Formula find difference between 2 cells of cancatenated data and tell me what column has the difference

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 data sets on 2 sheets in my workbook. They should match. There are 1000 rows and 57 columns. I have added a column to each data set that concats the columns of each row and a column that `xlookup` into the other dataset to find those that don't match.

Now I need to figure out how to find the column(s) in each row that don't match so that I can fix them.

Is there a formula that might work for showing me the column(s) in each row that don't match?

Here is a small sample of some of the data:

Data Set A

| Name | Type | ScanningIssues | Domain | OS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.1.21.10 | Unknown | 1 | Unknown | Not Scanned |
| Apogee-PC | VMware | 5 | Other Domain | Win 2016 |
| 71K318Z | Windows | 1 | My Domain | Win 7 |
| STAN | Network Device | 0 | My Domain | Linux |

Data Set B

| Name | Type | ScanningIssues | Domain | OS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.1.21.10 | Windows | 1 | Unknown | Win 10 |
| STAN | Network Device | 0 | My Domain | Linux |
| 71K318Z | Windows | 1 | My Domain | Win 10 |
| Apogee-PC | VMware | 2 | Other Domain | Win 2016 |

It's a mix of strings, numbers, dates, date/time, and empty cells

So, the results I would expect would be something like this:

| Name | Column(s) |
| --- | --- |
| 10.1.21.10 | 2,5 |
| STAN |  |
| 71K318Z | 5 |
| Apogee-PC | 3 |

Comment: What is your expected output? If A and B are different, how can you tell whether A or B is where the change was made?

Comment: It won't matter which data set is different. Data set A is the master and I have to keep it updated with the info in Data set B. So I only need to know which column(s) are different in each row so that I can go and check and fix them.

Comment: Is the data aligned, like in the example (Sheet1 row1 is compared to Sheet2 row 1; no need to lookup the line number?)

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not always perfectly aligned. Some are and some are not. The Name field is unique though so I'm able to look them up based on that.

Answer (score 0):

**OPTION 1:**

Regarding the sample data sets provided, let's assume **Data Set A** is located in `Sheet1!A1:E5` and **Data Set B** is located in `Sheet2!A1:E5` (including header rows).

First, use the CONCAT function to create a "*Unique ID*" column in BOTH data sets (which you've already done). In cell F2, use `=CONCAT(A2:E2)`, then copy the formula down to the bottom of each data set.

Next, use the ISNA and XMATCH functions to determine which values in the "*Unique ID*" column of **Data Set B** are not found in **Data Set A**. In cell G2, use `=ISNA(XMATCH(F2, Sheet1!$F$2:$F$5))`, then copy the formula down to the bottom of the data set. XMATCH on it's own will return either the row number where a match was found, or the #N/A error if no match was found. By wrapping XMATCH inside of ISNA, it will return FALSE if a match was found, or TRUE if no match was found.

Lastly, in cell H2 of **Data Set B**, use the following formula to return the column numbers for range B2:E2 that do not match with the corresponding record in **Data Set A**, then copy the formula down to the bottom of the data set:

```
=IF(G2,
TEXTJOIN(", ",, FILTER(SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(B2:E2), 2),
   B2:E2 <> XLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5, Sheet1!$B$2:$E$5))),
"")
```

Basically, if the "*Unique ID*" in cell G2 was not found, the XLOOKUP function is used to identify the row in Data Set A where the "*Name*" in cell A2 is found, then compare that row against range B2:E2 to determine which columns are not equal. This will return an array of TRUE's and FALSE's {TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE}, which is then used as the *include* parameter in the FILTER function. The *array* parameter is generated by combining the SEQUENCE and COLUMNS functions, which returns the column numbers of range B2:E2 in an array {2,3,4,5}. The filtered array {2,5} is then converted to the final comma-separated text string "2, 5" by wrapping everything inside the TEXTJOIN function.

To minimize the number of helper columns required, you can eliminate the formula in column H by merging it with column G, if desired. To do so, use the following nested formula in cell G2, then copy it down to the bottom of the data set:

```
=IF(
ISNA(XMATCH(F2, Sheet1!$F$2:$F$5)),
TEXTJOIN(", ",, FILTER(SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(B2:E2), 2),
   B2:E2 <> XLOOKUP(A2, Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5, Sheet1!$B$2:$E$5))),
"")
```

The final results should look something like this:

[image: filter_match_cols_by_row.jpg]

**OPTION 2:**

Using the same principles from Option 1 above, we can combine everything into a single-cell dynamic array, using the LET function to define all of the variables needed to produce the results. Try the following formula in a separate worksheet to return a filtered list of only the rows and columns that do not match, without the need for helper columns:

```
=LET(
range1, Sheet1!A2:BE1001,
range2, Sheet2!A2:BE1001,
join1, BYROW(range1, LAMBDA(r,CONCAT(r))),
join2, BYROW(range2, LAMBDA(r,CONCAT(r))),
items, FILTER(range1,ISNA(XMATCH(join1,join2)),"< None >"),
names, CHOOSECOLS(items,1),
col_nums, SEQUENCE(,COLUMNS(items)),
lookup_rng, CHOOSECOLS(range2,1),
results, BYROW(items, LAMBDA(r,
   LET(
   lookup_val, INDEX(r,1),
   match_cols, r=XLOOKUP(lookup_val,lookup_rng,range2),
   IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",,FILTER(col_nums,NOT(match_cols))),"ALL")))),
VSTACK({"Name","Column(s)"},HSTACK(names,results))
)
```

Adjust the range references for *range1* and *range2* to meet your needs. If one of the ranges contains new records, it should be entered as *range1*. Cheers!

Comment: By order do you mean all the rows line up so that row 1 in Data Set A should be equal to row 1 in Data Set B? If so then this won't work because they don't all match like that.

Comment: Fair enough. I saw your new comment up above where you said the Name field is unique, which is perfect. I'll see what I can come up with and post another answer...

Comment: Hey Mike, check out my edited answer above. It should work now, based on the new info provided.